# Error: Did not provide required argument

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have a generator called with yo generator:module [ModuleName] .
I want to handle the error when ModuleName argument is undefined and still be able to use generator:module --help without arguments.

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need to make the arguments non required.

Then if the argument was not provided, handle the case yourself as you see fit.